# Why PHP holds more than one type in array?

Tags: php

I'm beginner in PHP scripting.  As per my knowledge, array means collection of same types of elements but PHP violating that rule.

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <?php 
        $a = 10; 
        echo $a;

        $arr = array();

        for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
            $arr[$i] = $i * $i; // Integer values
        }

        $arr[10]="Rohit"; // string value
        $arr[11] = 10.15; // float value
        $arr[12] = true; // boolean value

        for($i = 0; $i < COUNT($arr); $i++){
            echo "<br>".$arr[$i];
        }

        echo "<br>Length of array: ".COUNT($arr);
        echo "var_dump output: ".var_dump($arr);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is what I got result:

```
10
0
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
Rohit
10.15
1
Length of array: 13

C:\wamp\www\phpModules\check16_6_18_study.php:28:
array (size=13)
  0 => int 0
  1 => int 1
  2 => int 4
  3 => int 9
  4 => int 16
  5 => int 25
  6 => int 36
  7 => int 49
  8 => int 64
  9 => int 81
  10 => string 'Rohit' (length=5)
  11 => float 10.15
  12 => boolean true

var_dump output:
```

You can notice first 10 elements are integers, 10th element is string, 11th element is float and 12th element is boolean.

Please anyone explain me why PHP has such confusing behavior?

Comment: every programming language is different

Comment: Maybe not directly related to your question, but here's an interesting read to help you understand PHP arrays and how they differ from arrays in many other languages: http://technosophos.com/2011/07/26/php-arrays-are-not-arrays.html

Comment: @Mike You got my problem and I got solution of my problem also. In PHP array is an ordered hash map and yes it is completely different than other languages. Thank you Mike. Your shared article was useful and I got answer to my question.

Comment: @RohitSawai PHP has what's known as [associative arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array).

Comment: @Mike But one question still remained: Why they have implemented array in such way?

Comment: @RohitSawai Probably ease of use, but your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: Why do you find this bad? I can't even think how horrible it would be to use an array where you only can have one data type in it. If it was limited the way you want it to be then it would probably mean sometimes you need about twice or more times the code. No thank you.

Comment: @Andreas I don't have a problem with anything. It's about concept which I have read and which I have understood. Concept of array is "Collection of same type of elements" but when I started PHP, the meaning of array is completely different. Why they didn't use different name for that concept? After this question I also understood that same thing happen in Python, JavaScript and in Ruby also. My question is why did they alter the meaning of Array and if they altered, then why didn't they assign new name to that concept?

Comment: Where did you read this *"Collection of same type of elements"*? Is it some old book from the 70's?

Comment: @Andreas When I typed just arrays in google I got this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and please correct me if I'm going wrong. Our instructors also gives the same definition of arrays.

Comment: And what language is that? Does that page say "learn PHP" or perhaps "learn java"?

Comment: @Andreas This [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_arrays.htm) link and read just first line. _An array is a data structure that stores one or more similar type of values in a single value._ Almost everywhere this concept has been given for arrays. That link of java I have given just for instance.

Comment: Why are you reading bull *cough* sites on the internet? Why not use the manual? www.php.net read it. If you had been there you would have seen that all the example shows mixing of strings and integers on both values and keys. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @Andreas Yes that's really cool guide and in first line they explained _An array in PHP is actually an ordered map_. Thank you and sure from now on I'll give first priority to manual rather than any other online learning material.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a language with a dynamic type system. Like most dynamic languages such as Python, Javascript, Ruby don't check types for anything by default. It's really just emergent behavior from how everything else works.

Comment: But there may be reason behind keeping those types dynamic and I want that reason. Then that array concept become completely confusing as per it's definition given in study materials.

Comment: Your study material must be focusing on other types of languages. For a dynamic language like PHP it wouldn't have made sense to force a specific type because that happened nowhere in the language. It's only since PHP5 that typechecks exists *at all*.

Comment: I'm using W3School and PHP Documentation for understanding PHP. I understood your answer but not got answer to my question. There may be reason behind using dynamic array and I'm not understanding what's that reason is? WHY? Why they have implemented arrays in that way?